# Sort array of objects as per days in week

Tags: php, sorting

I have datas of arrays of an object as below.

```
Array(

    [0]=>Object(
      [event_day]=>Tuesday
    )

    [1]=>Object(
      [event_day]=>Friday
    )

   [2]=>Object(
      [event_day]=>Wednesday
   ) 
 )
```

And I need to Sort according to week days starting from Monday like this one:

```
Array(

    [0]=>Object(
      [event_day]=>Tuesday
    )

    [1]=>Object(
      [event_day]=>Wednesday
    )

   [2]=>Object(
      [event_day]=>Friday
   ) 
 )
```

Comment: From where you got this data???

Comment: If this data is coming from the database your best place is to do it there. I.e `ORDER BY date;` If your doing something to your data first then you could also use a group by with the help of sqls built in date parser `day(date)`

Comment: What would be the length of array , share more info like 10 days or for duplicate.

Comment: There is no php function to sort by english day names. You first need to make a list where you order the days by yourself.

Comment: @Dough It is not from database . is there any other way :)

Comment: @Rishi There will be more than 50 data

Comment: @colburton could you please explain me a little more :)

Comment: Share example of at least 8-10 of days , how would you sort them ?

Comment: @Raju, could be there multiple repetitive days? like 3 Mondays, 5 Tursdays

Comment: @ RomanPerekhrest yes there will be repetitive days.

Answer (score 2):

Code that would sort your data:

```
$dataToSort = [
    (object)['event_day' => 'Tuesday'],
    (object)['event_day' => 'Friday'],
    (object)['event_day' => 'Wednesday'],
];

$dayOrder = [
    'Monday'    => 1,
    'Tuesday'   => 2,
    'Wednesday' => 3,
    'Thursday'  => 4,
    'Friday'    => 5,
    'Saturday'  => 6,
    'Sunday'    => 7,
];

usort($dataToSort,
    function ($a, $b) use ($dayOrder) {
        return $dayOrder[$a->event_day] > $dayOrder[$b->event_day];
    });

print_r($dataToSort);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [event_day] => Tuesday
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [event_day] => Wednesday
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [event_day] => Friday
        )

)
```

This way you can sort anything, not just days.

Answer (score 1):

The solution using `usort` and `array_search` functions:

```
// predefined weekdays list (in order)
$weekdays = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];

// $arr is your initial array    
usort($arr, function($a, $b) use($weekdays){
   return array_search($a->event_day, $weekdays) - array_search($b->event_day, $weekdays);
});

print_r($arr);
```